# interlink excel cell within a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel Workbook in which there are 4 sheet which has two cell name start date and end date, whose values should be same across all 4 sheet, I want that If I change the value in anyone of the sheets the other three sheets automatically update that values. And vice versa.

Comment: I dont know how to use VBA, can you guide me with VBA code.

Comment: The cells are named "start date" and "end date" and only have sheet-specific scope then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Workbook_SheetChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbook.SheetChange) event to update the same cells on every worksheet if any one of the cells changes.

---

For example, if each sheet has the named ranges `start_date` and `end_date` (where their scope is limited to that sheet only), changes made to any `start_date` or `end_date` range *on any sheet* will update the corresponding range on all the other sheets.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo SafeExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    With Sh
        If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("start_date")) Is Nothing Then
            For Each ws In Worksheets
                ws.Range("start_date").Value = Target.Value
            Next ws
        End If
        If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("end_date")) Is Nothing Then
            For Each ws In Worksheets
                ws.Range("end_date").Value = Target.Value
            Next ws
        End If
    End With

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

---

If you are referring to the cells by their address and not by a defined name, something like this could work:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo SafeExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    With Sh
        ' "A1" is the start date, change as needed
        If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
            For Each ws In Worksheets
                ws.Range("A1").Value = Target.Value
            Next ws
        End If
        ' "B1" is the end date, change as needed
        If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then
            For Each ws In Worksheets
                ws.Range("B1").Value = Target.Value
            Next ws
        End If
    End With

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

---

This code goes in the `ThisWorkbook` module in the VBA editor.

Comment: I have copoed and pasted the above code in the VBA editor of excel and and save the file as macro enable, and then click on run sub, a window pop-up and ask for module name, after fill the name the only option able is create,so I did the same, and then click on run.
After that I try to change the date in one of the worksheet but it didn't work. Instead of changing the date the name tag is removed from the sheet and a new date is being entered..

Comment: It doesn't sound like you've entered the code in the `ThisWorkbook` module. The code should run automatically; no need to try to manually run it. You can read more about Events at http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx

Comment: I have read the link provide, I have understand some of the concepts but it also rises some question in my mind lilke what is the use of this line " If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("start_date")) Is Nothing Then" in this code.
<BR>
I have created a demo file. can you please check it and make the require changes.The link of the file is:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VwMLu9jBKvNijWC1UpVaR90Ra0cKeTtC/view

Comment: @Karan Your named ranges were saved with the Workbook scope instead of the Worksheet scope. You need to go into the Name Manager, delete 'start_date' and 'end_date', and then enter those names in again for EACH worksheet. Click on 'New', type in 'start_date' and then select a worksheet in the 'Scope' menu. Repeat for 'end_date' and then repeat for each worksheet.

Comment: As for `If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("start_date")) Is Nothing Then`, it means "If the changed cell (Target) is included in the range "start_date", then (execute the inner logic of the `if` statement". In VBA, this is expressed as a double-negative: "If it is not the case that the intersection of the changed cell and the range "start_date" is nothing then". You could interpret that as: "If it IS the case that the intersection of the changed cell and the range "start_date" is SOMETHING (i.e., not empty) then". Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA for this but rather named ranges. Put your cursor in the input cell, say E5, for `start_date` and then click in the named range box (in the upper left corner of the worksheet grid, directly above column A). Type `start_date` over `E5` and hit `Enter`. Now, cell E5 is named `start_date`. If you use `=start_date` anywhere else in the workbook, it will refer to the current contents of cell E5. If you want to edit the named ranges in any way, go to the ribbon menu `FORMULAS -> Name Manager`.

If you want to do this with VBA for the sole purpose of learning VBA, I would recommend taking a VBA course instead. Udemy has some good ones that often go on sale for about $10, and I'm sure that there are plenty of free resources elsewhere as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not what OP is asking - _I want that If I change the value in anyone of the sheets the other three sheets automatically update that values. And vice versa._

Comment: I have tried using name tage, but what happens is if I change the value in the name tag cell, the formula bar shows that value instead of name