# Multiple Worksheet Change Events: Multiple Dropdowns

Tags: excel, vba, events, onchange, worksheet

I am trying to create a workbook where if I change a dropdown on 1 sheet, it automatically updates that same dropdown on a second sheet. These dropdowns will represent different scenarios and my purpose in creating this is to allow the end-user the ability to change the scenario dropdown from any sheet, rather than just one.

I used this reference to create a VBA for changing 1 dropdown -[Original VBA code referenced](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/use-two-drop-down-menus-to-control-each-other/21354e76-c8ab-4116-aff7-1916cd44b532) - and it worked correctly ([See example workbook to download](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmcGUE_vrclQ7TJf86wLLGH833FZ)). However, now I want to add the other 2 dropdowns so that if any changes are made to them it updates accordingly.

I'm also open to other solutions if you know of something better.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   Please refrain from using links to code, and rather inline the code in the question itself.

Comment: Maybe see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52121718/9245853) for an approach using the [Workbook.SheetChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange) event.

Comment: Thanks @HardcoreHenry for the feedback.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen. That was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this question was elementary -- I am new to VBA.

Using the example from the [Original VBA code referenced](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/use-two-drop-down-menus-to-control-each-other/21354e76-c8ab-4116-aff7-1916cd44b532), if you were looking to apply this rule to 2 sets of drop downs (4 total), instead of 1 set - you would duplicate the snippet from "If Not Intersect(..." to "..End if" and then update the reference to the 2nd set of cells.

EXAMPLE:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then ' watch only cell A1
    Set targetSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") ' define the sheet to copy to
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    targetSheet.Range("B1") = Target.Value ' copy to cell B1 on the target sheet
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then ' watch only cell A1
    Set targetSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") ' define the sheet to copy to
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    targetSheet.Range("B2") = Target.Value ' copy to cell B1 on the target sheet
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

You would then repeat for the other worksheet.

Comment: I edited your post by formatting the code segment. For future reference, you can do it by selecting the code block and hitting the `{}` button in the post editor.

Comment: Thanks, @TomBrunberg